# (Excel) If any one column of a certain set of columns contains a certain value, then output something

Tags: excel, if-statement

Yesterday I've been wrestling to get a working IF statement with AND & OR conditions, so far I haven't succeeded.

[image: Excel example]

In my picture you can see some of the columns I'm trying to test for certain values. If any of the highlighted columns contains a **1** I want to report in a new column the value **"No"**.

So far it seems I need to use a IF function with both AND & OR, but I haven't been able to get it right. Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this formula

```
=IF(OR(O1=1; R1=1; U1=1); "No"; "Yes")
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Now I'd like to enhance it a bit further. Would it also be possible to test those columns for **1 AND 2**? And if any one of those columns contains 1 or 2, still report the same Yes/No.

Comment: may be this will help =IF(OR(O1>0; R1>0; U1>0); "No"; "Yes")